# Pushing objects from an abstract class' subclass to a stack using HashMap?

Tags: java, stack, polymorphism, abstract

I am looking for a way to instantiate a subclass from an abstract class using a token from a hashMap and then push to my stack. Any insight would be appreciated

**Barn class**

```
 animalStack.push(new Animal("Cow"));
```

**Animal class:**

```
abstract class Animal {
  Map<String, Object> m1 = new HashMap<String,Object>();
  {
    m1.put("Cow", new Cow());
  }

  abstract int age();
}

class Cow extends Animal {
    @Override
    int age() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

For instance, I want the Cow object to be put into my animal stack.

Barn class: http://pastebin.com/4az10R8Q
Animal class: http://pastebin.com/hh9t7yzw

Comment: Can you be more specific about your question or provide more code? Btw you cannot instantiate abstract classes.

Comment: you can use factory pattern!! or create a method that will take string as input and return object correspondingly.

Comment: @LastFreeNickname I've edited the problem to include the source code. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [oHow to retrieve (and instantiate) hashmap objects using a base constructor of an abstract class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28226332/ohow-to-retrieve-and-instantiate-hashmap-objects-using-a-base-constructor-of-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you can't instantiate a `Cow` - because doing so will create an `Animal`, which will in turn try to populate it map with *another* `Cow` etc. (In fact you can't create *any* `Animal` instances for the same reason.)

It sounds like your map should actually be static, and you should have a static factory method:

```
abstract class Animal {
  private static final Map<String, Animal> map
      = new HashMap<String,Object>();

  static {
    map.put("Cow", new Cow());
  }

  static Animal getAnimal(String name) {
    // TODO: Validation
    return map.get(name);
  }

  abstract int age();
}
```

Then you can use:

```
animalStack.push(Animal.getAnimal("Cow"));
```

Note that this will push a reference to the same object each time you call it - you *might* want your `Animal.getAnimal` method to create a new instance on each call.